# How to reference an environment variable in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to reference an environment variable (a linux environment variable) in my Nifi Processors. I tried using expression language by referencing `${MY_VARIABLE_NAME}` directly in the properties of the processor. But this doesn't seem to work. Is this even possible ? If yes How can it be done ?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

You can reference environment variables in NiFi Expression Language as you describe.  If it is not working, you might check a few things:

- The processor property supports Expression Language
- The environment variable is defined for the NiFi process (try `${USER}` or `${PATH}` for contrast)
- There are no other attributes with the same name that have precedence over the environment variable in EL evaluation

This is briefly discussed in [Structure of a NiFi Expression](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#structure) in the NiFi Expression Language Guide with respect to escaping:

> For example, the following can be used to escape an attribute named “my attribute”: `${"my attribute"}` or `${'my attribute'}`.
>
> In this example, the value to be returned is the value of the "my attribute" value, if it exists. If that attribute does not exist, the Expression Language will then look for a System Environment Variable named "my attribute." If unable to find this, it will look for a JVM System Property named "my attribute." Finally, if none of these exists, the Expression Language will return a null value.

Comment: Hi James, referencing environment variables with expression langage works indeed, but only for variables that were declared before Nifi startup. I have the feeling that Nifi loads all the environment variables at startup and stops looking for new ones. Which explains that it didn't work for me at the first time. Is my claim true ?  could you please test and confirm this ? thank you.

Comment: Yes, you would have to restart NiFi to pick up new environment variables.  I don't believe this is unique to NiFi, it is normal behavior for environment variables.

Comment: I agree, but what if I wanted to add a new flow to my Nifi without stopping the existing flows. If the new flow references an environement variable, I would have to restart, same thing happens if I use custom properties file, as Nifi loads their content at startup !!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the proposal for [NiFi Variable Registry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Variable+Registry), which intends to provide dynamic and secure variable access.